# Does the separator contribute to the total height of an UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

If I had 1000 rows, would a single-line separator make the table view bigger in height? Or is it an overlay on a cell only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've made simple test application - created UITableView with 1000 rows and manually set its content offset:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [table reloadData];

    [table setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 44*500) animated:NO]; // rowHeight equals 44
}
```

Both with and without line separator table view scrolled to the same position. So it seems that line separator does not affect table's content size.

Answer (score -2):

It would make the table bigger!!! I think the separator has 1px in height.