# Does the rowHeight of a UITableViewCell account for the height of its separator?

Tags: uitableview, separator, row-height

I have a custom UITableViewCell nib that has an image on the left side occupying the entire height of the cell (similar to the grouped table views in the iTunes app). I have noticed that  sometimes the icons appear to obscure the separator line at the bottom of the cell they are associated with.

My question is this: in computing the height of the cell, should I add an additional 1 or 2 pixels (depending on the separator style) to account for the separator? Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I pointed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644296/does-the-separator-contribute-to-the-total-hight-of-an-uitableview) line separator does not affect contents size, so it seems separator is drawn in (or over) UITableView cell and so you indeed need to add those pixels to avoid your cell content to obscure separator.

Comment: That question is poorly phrased and poorly tagged, which explains why I didn't find it when I searched, but the conclusion is the same. Thanks.